# Null Pointer Exception using Checkbox

Tags: android

I am trying to show **Checkbox Status** by showing *Toast* whenever user do **Click** on *button* for that i am using AlertDialog, but getting Null Pointer Exception,

Complete Logcat:

```
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.example.UploadActivity$2.onClick(UploadActivity.java:271)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-12 06:32:44.851: E/AndroidRuntime(783):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 06:32:50.332: E/Trace(1213): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    SaveData();     
                    alertDialog.dismiss();

                    chkSubscribe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkSubscribe);
                    if (chkSubscribe.isChecked())
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"You have Subscribed for Newsletter",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }       
                    else {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"You have Un-subscribed for Newsletter",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
```

**Error Line:**

```
com.example.UploadActivity$2.onClick(UploadActivity.java:271)
```

**(i.e.):**

```
if (chkSubscribe.isChecked())
```

Comment: What does `chkSubscribe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkSubscribe);` returns ?

Comment: check if your checkbox placed in your activity's layout file or not ?

Comment: This might possible becuse you used another layout..

Comment: check your id of layout and activity of checkbox both should be same

Comment: make sure u set the correct layout e.g : `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: Is it possible that this checkbox was in dialog? Once you dismiss dialog your variable will be null.

Comment: @fliespl yes you are right.. i have updated my question please check now

Comment: @AbrahimNeil can u post some more code related to how you inflate `dialog_activity` for dialog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are inflating a layout for your `dialog` you need to use dialog object to initialize view

```
      chkSubscribe = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.chkSubscribe);
```

You are getting NPE coz you have not initialized `chkSubscribe`

`chkSubscribe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkSubscribe)` //Initialization fails

You are also dismissing the `dialog` in which case `chkSubscribe` will be null.

Note : You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling findViewById inside click, here it is not calling the findViewByid on the main activity class but the loginButton and loginButton does not have check box in it. you need to call this line "chkSubscribe = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chkSubscribe); " in Activity  and then reference it in the onClick method, remember any method you call on this object in onClick refer to loginButton not your activity