# when isChecked() of checkbox called in android, it gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, checkbox

I am new in android. i am trying to execute following code but the application crashes,
In following code, if condition causes the nullpointerexception which is in bold text
please check the following code......
I am sharing my code. thanks.....

```
private void showGroupChatDialog ()
    {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Imps.ProviderSettings.QueryMap settings = new Imps.ProviderSettings.QueryMap(
                cr, mLastProviderId, false /* don't keep updated */, null /* no handler */);

        String chatDomain = "conference." + settings.getDomain();

        settings.close();


     // This example shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_group_chat, null);
        final TextView tvServer = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.chat_server);

        tvServer.setText(chatDomain);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.create_or_join_group_chat)
            .setView(textEntryView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.connect, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */

                    String chatRoom = null;
                    String chatServer = null;
                    int enablegrouphistory;
                    //int opentoall;

                    TextView tv = (TextView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.chat_room);

                    chatRoom = tv.getText().toString();

                    tv = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.chat_server);

                    chatServer = tv.getText().toString();

                    **CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);
                    if (enablehistory.isChecked()) {
                        enablegrouphistory = 1;
                    }
                    CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
                    if(openall.isChecked()){
                        opentoall = 1;
                    }**

                    startGroupChat (chatRoom, chatServer, ((ImApp)getApplication()).getConnection(mLastProviderId));

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .create().show();

    }
```

Comment: use settextchangeedlistener on your checkbox..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null Pointer Exception using Checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608911/null-pointer-exception-using-checkbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace this

```
CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);
CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
```

With

```
 CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);
 CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the views belongs to `alert_dialog_group_chat.xml`.

So change

```
CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);
```

to

```
CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);
```

Similarly

```
CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
```

You are getting `NUllPointerException` as `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

you have given `TextView` like `textEntryView.findViewById` same like that give both `CheckBox` like `textEntryView.findViewById`

```
tv = (TextView) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.chat_server);

CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);
CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);

if (enablehistory.isChecked()) 
{
  enablegrouphistory = 1;
}
CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
if(openall.isChecked())
{
  opentoall = 1;
}
```

to

```
CheckBox enablehistory = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.enable_group_history);

if (enablehistory.isChecked()) 
{
  enablegrouphistory = 1;
}
CheckBox openall = (CheckBox) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.open_to_all);
if(openall.isChecked())
{
  opentoall = 1;
}
```

You are inflating your layout in `textEntryView` so you need to get your `View` from there